# Creating a function in postgresql dont make INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql

cursreg returns all rows on "continguts" that not have registers on classcont. (this is ok)
But i need to insert on "classcont" the int recived on function (classificado int) for each result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fclassifica(clasificado int) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
registre RECORD;
        cursreg CURSOR FOR SELECT c.idcontingut FROM continguts as c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM classcont as ca
WHERE c.idcontingut = ca.contingut);
BEGIN
OPEN cursreg;
LOOP
FETCH FROM cursreg INTO registre;
INSERT INTO classcont (class,contingut)
VALUES (clasificado, registre.idcontingut);
RAISE NOTICE 'La classificació de ID ha estat modificada' ;

END LOOP;
CLOSE cursreg;
RETURN ;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a cursor or even PL/pgSQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fclassifica(p_clasificado int) 
  RETURNS void 
AS
$$
  INSERT INTO classcont (class, contingut)
  select p_clasificado, c.idcontingut
  FROM continguts as c
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM classcont as ca
                    WHERE c.idcontingut = ca.contingut);
$$
language sql;
```